# Android 2D drawing onto a canvas in a async task, am i doing it right?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

i have written a program to render a pitching and rotating ball in 2D (its a 2D version of a real 3D compass, the type the has a floating sphere that follows north and tilts when the frame tilts)

its working fine, but taking 30mS to draw to the canvas/bitmap without the rotation matrix and 60mS with the rotation matrix.

the draw code happens in an asyncTask doInBackground because it gets data from a socket. after its done creating the bitmap it does a publish progress. so the code looks like this (stripped a lot out)

```
Bitmap mRotatedBmp = null;
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // read pitch and roll data from socket and loop forever

        int wh=448, c=wh/2, r=wh*100/220;
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(wh, wh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

            // do some drawing like this
            canvas.drawCircle(c, c, r, paint);
            paint.setColor(skycolor);
            canvas.drawArc(oval, 180, 180, true, paint)
    etc, total 1 circle, 2 arcs, 1 rectangle and several paths and a bit of text

//takes 30mS to here
        // ROTATION PART 
        // mRotatedBmp is the thing that gets displayed in publishProgress
        mRotatedBmp  = Bitmap.createBitmap(wh, wh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas rotatedCanvas = new Canvas(mRotatedBmp );
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(-rollD,r,r);
        rotatedCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, new Paint());
 //takes 60mS to here  

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {


        imageView.setImageBitmap(mRotatedBmp  );        // draw new img to screen
        imageView.invalidate();
```

So i wonder if i'm drawing onto the wrong thing. basically its a 450x450 image consisting of a total of 1 circle, 2 arcs, 1 rectangle and several paths and a bit of text

thanks for any ideas how to speed up

Comment: I think a `SurfaceView` would be more appropriate to your requirements. `AsyncTask`s are more suited for relatively short operations.

Answer (score -1):

i figured out the problem has very little to do with the drawing and 90% with the create bitmap.

if i move the Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(wh, wh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); out of the loop, do it just once, then i'm getting about 6mS draw time

the problem is now i'm drawing into on screen memory so lots of flashing but can fix that with double buffering